# Was bedeutet „Wat kiekstn so, Fatzke?“

Tags: english-to-german, dialect, slang

Ich weiß, dass dies ein klassisches Sprichwort aus Berlin ist. Auch, dass es vielleicht nicht so freundlich ist. Aber ich kann es doch nicht verstehen. Ich würde sehr dankbar sein, wenn Sie dieses Sprichwort erklären oder auf Englisch übersetzen könnten.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Kieken** ist das berlinerische Wort für **gucken, schauen**. *Kiekstn* ist eine Kontraktion von *kiekst du denn*.

**Fatzke** bezeichnet einen *dummen, [eitlen](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/eitel) Menschen*.

Der Satz, nach dem du fragst, ist übrigens kein [Sprichwort](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/sprichwort), und ins Englische übersetzt hieße es:

> What are you looking at, you snob?

Und im Hochdeutschen:

> Was guckst du denn so, du Schnösel / Lackaffe?

Comment: Aus von Langenscheidt "Liliput" little Berlinerische wörterbuch (2011), pg 99:
"Fatzke; der eitler [vain],  arroganter Mensch:  dit is doch 'n oller Fatzke".